# how can i use a Feature name like a inner text condition in a <UI> </UI> frame?

Tags: wix, wix3

i want to use a Feature state like inner text in a Publish element.

this is my code:

```
<Feature Id="Complete" Title="App"
         Display="expand" Level="1" AllowAdvertise='no' InstallDefault='local'> 
 ...
</Feature> 

<UI>
 ...
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg"> ¿¿¿????</Publish>
 ...
</UI>
```

I want to replace the ¿¿¿¿???? for something like "(&Complete = 3)"

Answer (score 3):

You just need to [escape the XML](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/4/21/How-to-escape-the-ampersand-in-WiX-and-MSI-UI).

Something like `&amp;Complete=3`